# How to print the current time with fractional seconds, using fmt library

Tags: c++, c++-chrono, fmt

This code

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <fmt/chrono.h>
...
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
fmt::print("The time is: {:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}\n", now);
```

Prints this:

> The time is: 2023-01-02 15:51:23

How do I get it to print sub-second precision, for example, milliseconds? Something like:

> The time is: 2023-01-02 15:51:23.753

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have to do this in two steps -- YMD and HM followed by the high-res seconds. Here is a worked example, using `fmt` version 9.0 on Ubuntu:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <fmt/chrono.h>

int main() {
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto sse = now.time_since_epoch();
    fmt::print("{:%FT%H:%M:}{:%S}\n", now, sse);
    exit(0);
}
```

for which I get

```
$ g++ -o answer answer.cpp -lfmt; ./answer 
2023-01-02T16:26:17.009359309
$
```

---

(Initial, earlier, slightly off attempt to reason based on `spdlog` follows. But `spdlog` wraps `fmt` and overlays its format.)

It is on the [format page](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/wiki/3.-Custom-formatting), you want something like `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%e`. Note that `%e`, `%f` and `%F` give you milli, micro and nanoseconds. Edit: That was the [spdlog](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog) format though.

Here is a quick example, for simplicity from my R package [RcppSpdlog](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppspdlog) accessing [fmt](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog) via [spdlog](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog):

```
> library(RcppSpdlog)
> RcppSpdlog::log_set_pattern("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f] [%L] %v")
> RcppSpdlog::log_warn("Hello")
[2023-01-02 15:00:49.746031] [W] Hello
> RcppSpdlog::log_set_pattern("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%e] [%L] %v")
> RcppSpdlog::log_warn("World")
[2023-01-02 15:01:02.137] [W] World
>
```

Note the display of micro- and milliseconds as stated.

*Edit:*  There is something else going on with your example. Here is a simplified answer, printing *only* seconds and it comes by default fractionally down to nanoseconds (for me on Linux):

```
$ cat answer.cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <fmt/chrono.h>

int main() {
    fmt::print("{:%S}\n", std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
    exit(0);
}
$ g++ -o answer answer.cpp -lfmt
$ ./answer 
02.461241690
$
```

Comment: Hmm. My question is about the `fmt` library, not `spdlog`. And adding a `%f` doesn't compile for me. `%e` doesn't work - it keeps printing "2". I'm guessing it's  the day of the week.

Comment: I'm looking into how to make vcpkg update. I think it's using 9.0.0 of fmt, but I see a 9.1.0 on their website.

Comment: I am using 9.1 via spdlog. I would be surprised if not at least `%e` worked with 9.0 and before.

Comment: Hm, looking at the release note for 9.1 it does seem that `chrono` formatting got enhanced.  Well you can try to upgrade to 9.1, or try another formatter / chrono wrapper like Howard Hinnant's `date`.

Comment: I can replicate the 'always print 2' under `%2` using the 9.0 system library under Ubuntu.

Comment: You're latest update there, for 9.0, seems to be working for me on macOS 13.1. 

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the iterations: "today I learned" that `spdlog` has its own format strings.  Makes sense, come to think about it, as `chrono` object have similar formating in `CCTZ`, `Date`, and other libraries wrapped around it.

Comment: If you could remove the `spdlog` part, or put it as an aside at the end, I'll accept this answer. I just upgraded to `fmt` 9.1 and still none of the %f, %e, %F works. Your second suggestion to use the `time_since_epoch` works.

Comment: Done. I think the 'two step approach' is also needed with other time libraries wrapping `chrono`.

Comment: This chrono-wrapping library only needs one step: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date:  `cout << format("%Y-%m-%d %T\n", now);`

Comment: Nice, I am fairly sure I needed two steps with CCTZ as well, but spdlog also (like your Date) gets by with one higher-level.  (I pointed OP at Date earlier here too...)

Answer (score 1):

Just share my way to output fractional seconds in logging:

```
std::string Timestamp() {
    namespace c = std::chrono;
    auto tp = c::time_point_cast<c::microseconds>(c::system_clock::now());
    auto us = tp.time_since_epoch().count() % std::micro::den;
    return fmt::format("{:%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S}.{:06d}", tp, us);
}
```

There is a pull request to output fractional seconds for formatting `time_point`, (but closed, the author did not continue the work):

https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/pull/2292

My concern is that change `%S` to include fractional part is some-what breaking change (`strftime` defines it as seconds from  `00` to `60`). I hope `fmtlib` would consider some other way to tackle this requirement.

Comment: More info from `fmtlib`: https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/2207